# Find the number of simple paths from A to B going through a given point on the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

I am looking into an interesting issue in networks.

Given an undirected graph which can contain cycles:

I choose two points, A and B as origin and end of my paths. My goal is to calculate how many simple paths go through each of the other nodes in the graph.

For example, in this graph:
[image: In this graph]

there are 4 simple paths from 0 to 4. Node 3 has a count of 4, nodes 1 and 2 have a count of 2.

Brute forcing this is impossible, since it would require finding all simple paths, which is on the order of O(n!).
I tried to make a variation of the Floyd–Warshall algorithm, but I cannot find a good recursive formula - I can only manage to count all paths, not only simple ones.

Is there a solution to this problem in polynomial time?

Thank you!

Comment: Please define a simple path.

Comment: Sorry! Here, a simple path is one that never goes through the same node twice, i.e. has no cycles.

Comment: That is the usual definition of a path.  "In graph theory, a path in a graph is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which joins a sequence of vertices which, by most definitions, are all distinct" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)

Comment: "Brute forcing this is impossible"  Not impossible.  For a graph of 4,700 vertices and 27,000 edges, it takes about 20 seconds on a modest laptop if efficiently implemented.  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/All-Paths#performance

Comment: @ravenspoint That’s a fairly sparse graph. I’d imagine on denser graphs that no algorithm would finish in a reasonable amount of time (e.g. take a complete graph of 50 nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best anyone knows, no, there isn’t a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem. The problem of counting how many s-t simple paths there are in a graph - not even listing them, just counting them - is [#P-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-hard-is-counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-directed). Since [a polynomial-time algorithm for a #P-complete problem would prove P = NP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete), there are no known polynomial-time algorithms for this problem.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why my dp approaches weren't working. I appreciate it